# Tomato Firmware producing high cpu load average (but low cpu usage)

Tags: cpu-usage, tomato, cpu-load

I using an Asus RT-N18U router with the "Advanced Tomato" firmware with shibby's firmware under the hood.
I recognized a constant cpu load average of 2.00, but at the same time a low cpu usage.

"top" giving me the following result:

```
Mem: 42520K used, 213112K free, 204K shrd, 5348K buff, 13408K cached
CPU:  0.0% usr  0.0% sys  0.0% nic  100% idle  0.0% io  0.0% irq  0.0% sirq
Load average: 2.08 2.03 1.98 1/42 2404
PID  PPID USER     STAT   VSZ %VSZ CPU %CPU COMMAND
 1537     1 root     S     2844  1.1   0  0.0 httpd
 1273     1 nobody   S     1688  0.6   0  0.0 dnsmasq -c 4096 --log-async
    1     0 root     S     1612  0.6   0  0.0 /sbin/preinit
  718     1 root     S     1600  0.6   0  0.0 blink_5g
  716     1 root     S     1596  0.6   0  0.0 buttons
  719     1 root     S     1532  0.6   0  0.0 console
  808     1 root     S     1512  0.5   0  0.0 nas
  873     1 root     S     1512  0.5   0  0.0 nas
  896     1 root     S     1408  0.5   0  0.0 crond -l 9
 1266     1 root     S     1396  0.5   0  0.0 udhcpc -i vlan2 -b -s dhcpc-event
 2233  2232 root     S     1392  0.5   0  0.0 -sh
 2404  2233 root     R     1388  0.5   0  0.0 top
  721   719 root     S     1388  0.5   0  0.0 /bin/sh
```

and so on ...

- VPN Server/Client disabled
- no big difference if logging is disabled or not
- no difference if wifi is on/off
- Version: Tomato Firmware 1.28.0000 -3.5-140 K26ARM USB AIO-64K
- CPU temperature ~78°C (wtf?)

Any suggestions where to tweak the knobs?

Thanks a lot so far and please be patient with my first post here :)

Greetings,
Tom